# Debug javascript epub3 code

Tags: epub

How can I debug a script write in a epub3 .js file? The script in question read with an xmlhttprequest a file and do some operation with the extracted text. Parsing the file is ok but other operations no. So I'm looking for a debugger but I can't use the FF or IE or Chrome built in debugger because transport all the pages and the script externally of the epub3 file is not my choice. I need to debug and see the wysiwyg of the xhtml code. Actually I use Sigil with the last release published.
Another solition could be change colors code in my .js file: actually it is located in Misc folder and all the code is black without colors that could help me reading better than now.
Any help or suggestion world be appreciated.
Than at all

Answer (score 1):

I use HTML Sandbox. It's from W3 Schools. I get some false positives (easily identifiable) but it works for me. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not knowledgeable enough about JS to  answer your question, but epubcheck is the most common tool for validating epub files. It usually provides error messages and logs.

I could be wrong, but I assume  you could use the same debug tools for JS which you'd use for browser scripting. That would probably be your most useful information. As long as it works in the browser and validates with epubcheck, that's probably what you need.

Reading systems have different support for scripting and aside from maybe Kindle Beta Previewer (which does provide an output log of some sort). I wouldn't expect there to be any epub-specific debugging tools -- except just testing on reading systems.  Scripting support on reading systems still isn't that consistent.